# What are the Cartan geometries modeled on $\mathbb{H}P^m$?

Tags: quaternionic-geometry, cartan-geometry

I am not an expert on Cartan Geometry (in fact, I have just read and understood the definition, at a basic level). I have the following questions:

1) Can someone please describe what are the Cartan geometries modeled on $\mathbb{H}P^m$?

2) (possibly naive, and may be true/false for trivial reasons) Can any Quaternion-Kähler manifold of dimension $4m$ of positive curvature be modeled by such a Cartan geometry, as in question 1)?

Comment: I suppose that you mean to have as model the quaternionic projective space acted on by isometries, not the larger group of quaternionic projective linear transformations. There is certainly no classification of Cartan geometries modelled on quaternionic projective spaces. The possibility of torsion allows these Cartan geometries to be much more general than quaternionic Kaehler metrics.

Comment: Indeed every quaternionic Kaehler structure is an example of a torsion-free Cartan geometry with this model. This is clear since it is a first order structure, so you only need to get the structure group correct, and then the compactness of structure group gives an invariant connection. Torsion-freedom ensures that the connection is valued in the structure group.

Comment: @BenMcKay, thank you for your comments. I have not yet seen the definition of torsion in the setting of Cartan geometries (I have only read the wikipedia page, with a few bits and pieces from previous readings). Is there a 1-1 correspondence between QK structures and torsion-free Cartan geometries modeled on $\mathbb{H}P^m$, with the structure group being $Sp(m+1)$?

Comment: If the torsion vanishes, then the splitting into a soldering form and connection form will give a torsion-free connection with holonomy in $Sp(1)Sp(m)$, hence a quaternionic Kaehler metric. This observation seems to be of no use in trying to find or understand quaternionic Kaehler metrics; the theory of Cartan connections is (so far) more of an elegant formalism than a useful tool.

Comment: I see. It is more like an interesting way to package the connection form with the soldering form together, rather than a "tool". Ok, thank you for your comments.